# Gaufrette via FTP does not work correctly

Tags: php, symfony, ftp, gaufrette

Im using Gaufrette to fetch PDF files over FTP

```
knp_gaufrette:
  adapters:
    invoice_ftp:
      ftp:
        host: ftp.localhost
        port: 21
  filesystems:
    invoice:
      adapter: invoice_ftp
```

And Im downloading the file with

```
$url = sprintf('upload/%s/%s.%s', $this->getFolderName($file), $file, $extension);
$file = $this->filesystem->get($url);
$content = $file->getContent();
file_put_contents($newfile, $content);
```

But this gives me a error in the PDF file

But if im using

```
$url = sprintf('ftp://ftp.localhost/upload/%s/%s', $this->getFolderName($filename), $filename . '.PDF');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents($newfile, $content);
```

Is this a bug in gaufrette, or am I using gaufrette wrong?
I heard something about its maybe trying to use binary mode in gaufrette instead of ascii mode, but I dont know how to change this

Comment: Can you please provide me the script you used for download PDF via FTP. I am new to Symfony and could not configure the library for FTP download. If possible please let me know the developer guide to set up this library in Symfony. My goal is to copy a files from FTP directory to local. Please help.

Comment: I have changed my filesystem to use league/flysystem provided by https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing my adapter from `mode` `FTP_ASCII` (default) to `FTP_BINARY` it worked like a charm.

```
knp_gaufrette:
  adapters:
    invoice_ftp:
      ftp:
        host: ftp.localhost
        port: 21
        mode: FTP_BINARY
```

Comment: To explain why: ASCII mode will change the line ending character by default (ie. from CRLF to LF).